# How to deploy wss using SuperWebSocket in Windows C#

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I am trying to load .pem certificate file in the following SuperWebSocket code.

```
var config = new ServerConfig();
config.Ip = xx.xx.xx.xx;
config.Port = 2012;            
config.Security = "Tls";
config.Certificate = new CertificateConfig
{
    FilePath = @"C:/certificates/certificate.pem",                        
    ClientCertificateRequired = true
};
_s = new WebSocketServer();
_s.Setup(config);
```

And I started server, failed to load `wss://url:2012` but `ws://url:2012` is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert pem certificate file into pfx format. It must for .NET version.

Sample code:

```
var config1 = new ServerConfig();
config1.Ip = brokerIP;
config1.Port = brokerPort;
config1.Security = "Tls";
config1.Certificate = new CertificateConfig
{
    FilePath = @"C:\java_cer\certificate.pfx",
    ClientCertificateRequired = true
};
//start user sessions listener
if (_brokerServer.Setup(config1))
{
    if (!_brokerServer.Start())
    {
        result = "Failed to setup user listener";
    }
}
else
{
    result = "Failed to start user listener";
}
```